# Como atribuir o custo da query em uma variável no Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Para pegar o custo *estimado* da query uso o `EXPLAIN SELECT coluna FROM tabela;`, para pegar o custo *atual* da query uso o `EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT coluna FROM tabela;`, minha dúvida é como buscar o custo da query de forma automática, sem ter que executar manualmente e pegar o valor de olho.

Segue como exemplo uma função de como seria:

```
DECLARE custo integer;
DECLARE maiorcusto integer;
DECLARE query text;

maiorcusto := 0;
i := 0;
query = '';

WHILE i < array_length( queries ,1) LOOP

    custo := explain analyse queries[i];

    IF custo > maiorcusto THEN

        maiorcusto := custo;
        query := queries[i];

    END IF;

    i := i+1;

END LOOP;
```

A ideia é criar um script para buscar as queries num `log` e executar no `psql`, ou copiar as queries do `log` para uma tabela no banco e executar com `plain sql` e verificar as mais custosas, no momento é só o que procuro, depois me preocupo com o custo real da query ( **"custo"** X **"vezes executadas no período de tempo"** ), custo de `INSERT`, `UPDATE` e `DELETE` entre outras coisas.

Espero que isso seja possível, se não for, há outra maneira de buscar queries custosas sem ser verificando uma a uma ?

Editado:

Esqueci de informar, uso Postgres 9.1.

**SOLUÇÃO:**

Baseado na resposta do @Clodoaldo Neto :

```
CREATE or REPLACE function custo_consulta(_consulta text[])
returns table (consulta text, custo_execucao numeric, tempo_execucao numeric ) as '
declare custo text;
begin
    foreach consulta in array _consulta loop
        execute ''EXPLAIN ( FORMAT JSON, ANALYZE ) '' || consulta INTO custo;
        custo_execucao := split_part(split_part(custo, ''"Total Cost": '', 2), '','', 1);
        tempo_execucao := split_part(split_part(custo, ''"Actual Total Time": '', 2), '','', 1);
        return next;
    end loop;
end;
' language plpgsql;

SELECT *
FROM custo_consulta(array['SELECT COUNT(*) FROM syo_evento WHERE id_grupoevento = ''OPORTUNIDADE''', 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM syo_evento WHERE id_grupoevento = ''REVISAO'''])
ORDER BY custo_execucao desc;

Result
---------------------------------------------------------------------  -----------------  ----------------- 
consulta                                                               custo_execucao     tempo_execucao    
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM syo_evento WHERE id_grupoevento = 'REVISAO'       38426,44           128,267           
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM syo_evento WHERE id_grupoevento = 'OPORTUNIDADE'  38252,65           123,996
```

Só tem mais um problema, recebe erro ao usar **$$** e teria que duplicar os `'` nas queries antes de passar para function, mas isso deverá ser corrigido.

Comment: Quanto ao erro do $$ você está usando um driver? JDBC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz passando um array de consultas mas pode ser também consultando uma tabela de consultas. SQL dinâmico.

```
create or replace function custo_consulta(_consulta text[])
returns table (consulta text, planejamento numeric, execucao numeric) as $$
declare custo text;
begin
    foreach consulta in array _consulta loop
        execute 'explain ' || consulta into custo;
        custo := split_part(split_part(custo, '(cost=', 2), ' rows=', 1);
        execucao := split_part(custo, '..', 1);
        planejamento := split_part(custo, '..', 2);
        return next;
    end loop;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

select *
from custo_consulta(array['select 1','select 1/1'])
order by planejamento + execucao desc;
  consulta  | planejamento | execucao 
------------+--------------+----------
 select 1   |        0.001 |    0.002
 select 1/1 |        0.001 |    0.001
```

Comment: Ótimo cara, é bem o que quero, eu estava chegando em uma solução usando `( FORMAT JSON )` e `substring()` para pegar o valor, mas ficou muito feio o código, só fiz algumas alterações na sua function, __primeiro__ o $$, não sei por que sempre me da erro, tenho que corrigir isto uma hora, __segundo__ o `actual time` é o tempo de execução do `explain` e é variável, dependendo da carga do servidor pode variar bastante, portanto alterei para pegar o `cost`, vou colocar como ficou na pegunta, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @Tiago se você vai usar só o custo estimado então basta `explain`. O `explain analyze` realmente executa a consulta e incorre em todo o custo da consulta além de causar os efeitos da consulta como insersão, deleção, locks, etc... O `actual time` é o tempo da consulta. O tempo do `explain` aparece nas duas últimas linhas e inclui o tempo da consulta.

Comment: Tem razão, alterei para buscar o "Actual time", se precisar apenas do custo usarei sem `analyse`, também editei para usar formato JSON assim não depende do "Aggregate" no inicio, se precisar de "Startup Time" ou qualquer outro dado saberei como buscar, obrigado.